# Inserir Imagem no codigo, SetImage Android, Erro ao fazer dinamica no java

Tags: java, android

```
ImageView img = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.img);
//Atualizando a imagem dinamicamente. A classe R é utilizada para acessar o recurso.
img.setImageResource(R.drawable.img);
```

Acontece um erro , queria saber onde estou errando

Comment: "Acontece um erro" - Mas qual ? Sem sabermos qual é o erro é literalmente impossível de ajudar.

Answer (score 0):

Tente da seguinte forma

```
SeuContexto.getDrawable(R.drawable.img)
```

Comment: Nada. o erro persiste

Comment: Edite sua pergunta  e coloque o erro por favor.@VitorGiovanny